# Use controls from 2 different libraries in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to vary between using controls from different namespaces in WPF (from `MahApps.Metro` and `MaterialDesignInXaml`), however I'm not really sure how to phrase this and Google didn't yield any helpful results.

What I'm trying to do is use the `MaterialDesignInXaml`'s textbox in a window, yet keep all other controls from `MahApps`, is this even possible, and if so, is it worth it?

Namespace references:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
```

XAML (Hope to make this the MaterialDesign one):

```
<TextBox Margin="30,50">

</TextBox>
```

Comment: Yes you can as the answer below points. IMO it's not worth it. Is the MahApps not have the style you need? Modify it. The functionality, extend it.

Comment: @kenny more the whole textbox, and the way it animates, sadly it can't be styled, as the Metro Textbox is just the standard windows one, however the MaterialDesign one has a nice animation when focused on it, which would be much more suited towards my current project.

Comment: So you're talking about the styling? For example, you want some `TextBox`'s to use styling from one library/namespace and others to use styling from another library/namespace?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yeah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look into the WPF demo from MahApps

https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/tree/master/MainDemo.Wpf

More or less: to get the styles working you have to refer them in the Style property [as can be seen here](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/Buttons.xaml#L33)

to get them working as "default" style, is a different question.
This should work by using a separate style with the basedOn attribute set:
`<Style basedOn="{StaticResource StyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type TargetControl}"/>`

**Original Answer**

In the very top of your file, you find the root node of your XAML, there you have to add a new XAML namespace refering to your controls

`xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:Actual.Namespace.Of.Classes;assembly=AssemblyTheyAreInside"`

afterwards, you can use that namespace to access the controls like any other as long as you prefix it with the xaml namespace

`<myns:acontrol />`

if you start writing `xmlns:myns` intellisense should also present you the available namespaces

Further hints:

- `myns` can be anything you like
- you can refer as many namespaces as you like
- Namespaces might be grouped under an URL

Comment: I've referenced both namespaces, and I can get exclusive controls from both, but what I'm trying to get is a "vanilla" control if you will, so whenever I create a textbox it just uses the Metro one

Comment: So that you just "use" eg. `<TextBox .../>` and it applies the metro style?

proper examples could help to understand what you want more clear :)

Comment: alright ,I think I see what needs to be done :), thanks alot!

Comment: @peaches There's a guide about using Material Design along with MahApps. Basically, you manually set the Style of a control to either the Material Design or MahApps style. You can also add Resources to your App.xaml that themselves refer to either MahApps or Material Design so you can easily switch between them.
See the Getting Started guide as well as: https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/MahApps.Metro-integration

Comment: @DavidSchwartz oh great! I must've missed that somehow, thank you